# Convert DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS.SSS to Progress DATETIME-TZ

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Is there an easy way to convert a date time value in format DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS.SSS to Progress DATETIME-TZ. For example, I am trying to store "15-Sep-2017 20:51:14.566" date in to Progress ABL variable whose datatype is datetime-tz with format "99/99/9999 HH:MM:SS.SSS+HH:MM".

I can get this working by splitting date, month, year, hours, minutes etc to individual variables and combining them using functions like DATE, DATETIME. But, I believe that there should be some good way of doing this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I agree that there should be, but as of yet I've never found a useful date function in Progress. I always have to either do string manipulation or use the functions you have described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry about the Progress displayformat - as long as you convert your string to a `datetime-tz` you can always play around with display format later.

In this case I think you need to do it the "hard" way. Here's something to get you started.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cDateString AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE dtDate      AS DATETIME-TZ NO-UNDO.

FUNCTION convertDateString RETURNS DATETIME-TZ (INPUT pcString AS CHARACTER):

    DEFINE VARIABLE dtDateTz AS DATETIME-TZ NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE cDateTz  AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE iMonth AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.    

    CASE ENTRY(2, pcString, "-"):
        WHEN "Jan" THEN iMonth = 1.
        WHEN "Feb" THEN iMonth = 2.
        WHEN "Mar" THEN iMonth = 3.
        WHEN "Apr" THEN iMonth = 4.
        WHEN "May" THEN iMonth = 5.
        WHEN "Jun" THEN iMonth = 6.
        WHEN "Jul" THEN iMonth = 7.
        WHEN "Aug" THEN iMonth = 8.
        WHEN "Sep" THEN iMonth = 9.
        WHEN "Oct" THEN iMonth = 10.
        WHEN "Nov" THEN iMonth = 11.
        WHEN "Dec" THEN iMonth = 12.
    END CASE.

    IF iMonth = 0 THEN RETURN ?.

    ASSIGN 
        cDateTz = SUBSTRING(ENTRY(3, pcString, "-"), 1 ,4) + "-" + STRING(iMonth) + "-" + ENTRY(1, pcString, "-") + " " + ENTRY(2, pcString, " ").

    dtDateTz = DATETIME-TZ(cDateTz).

    RETURN dtDateTz.

END FUNCTION. 


cDateString = "15-Sep-2017 20:51:14.566".

dtDate = convertDateString(cDateString).

DISPLAY dtDate FORMAT "99/99/9999 HH:MM:SS.SSS+HH:MM".
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but for the benefit of others who may find this:  simple variable assignment will work.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE dt  AS DATETIME.
DEFINE VARIABLE dtz AS DATETIME-TZ /* FORMAT "..." */.

dt = NOW.
dtz = dt.
DISPLAY dt SKIP dtz.
```

[Edit]
You can use the session variable `SESSION:TIMEZONE` to set the time zone used in this assignment.  But there have been issues with that in older versions of Progress, and you may need to use the startup parameter `-useSessionTZ`.  See the Progress KB article:  [Inconsistency assigning datetime-tz to datetime](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Inconsistency-assigning-datetime-tz-to-datetime)